# Why is ngOnInit not the first lifecycle hook?

Tags: angular, lifecycle

I'm new to Angular 2. Why is `ngOnInit` not the first hook that is called after the constructor of a component or directive?

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ngOnInit()` is called after `ngOnChanges()` was called the first time.

This ensures that initial values bound to inputs are available when `ngOnInit()` is called. `ngOnChanges()` is called after inputs were updated.

There were quite some discussions about the order of the first `ngOnChanges()` and `ngOnInit()` but none of the arguments were considered strong enough to change anything.

Comment: What problem(s) would I potentially have if the first `ngOnChanges` was called _after_ `ngOnInit`?

Comment: That the input values would not yet be available. If you don't need them, you can use the constructor.

Comment: Accepted because that makes a lot of sense, but I still can't imagine what sort of stuff I might want to do in `ngOnInit` that I can't do without those initial values. I still imagine it's more likely for `ngOnChanges` to require something from `ngOnInit` instead of the other way around.

Comment: The constructor is run before the first `ngOnChanges()`. When `ngOnInit()` is called the initial bindings to inputs are already passed to the component, only stuff that arrives later like from async calls is usually not yet available.